# Convert text file separated with line breaks to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, fetch-api

I have a text file filled with dictionary words that looks something like this:

```
banana
apple
orange
lemon
grape
```

and I want to be able to convert it to an array so that I can use it in a JavaScript file I am writing:

```
["banana", "apple", "orange", "lemon", "grape"]
```

For context, I'm making a request to the text file with the Fetch API. Does anyone know how I would be able to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is separated with line breaks `\n`. You can split into an array using `split("/n")`. In the event that there are spaces in your text, you should `map` that array through a `trim()` filter to remove the spaces.

```js
let pre = document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML;
//without trimming
let arr = pre.split("\n");
console.log(arr)

//with trim
let trimmed = pre.split("\n").map(e=>e.trim());
console.log(trimmed)
```

```html
<pre>
banana     
apple   
orange  
lemon
grape  
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

These words are separated with enter (`\n`). You can just split it by `\n` and the array will create by itself. Here's the example:

```js
let text = "banana\napple\norange\nlemon\ngrape"

let arr = text.split('\n')
console.log(arr)
```

**Outut**

```
[ 'banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'lemon', 'grape' ]
```

The evidence that words in files are separated by `\n`:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('words.txt', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
    let arr = data.split('\n')
    console.log(arr)
})
```

`words.txt` should be the file with words you mentioned in the question.